# How to run code at static-type checking time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, type-hinting

I wish to run code at the time code is inspected by the interpreter (preferably PyCharm but mypy related answers or others are also fine). The code I want to run is a signature-altering code such that the IDE will better show dynamically added members, or signatures.

In other words, is there some reserved keyword, or `__name__` that allows something like the following:

```py
# <code>

if __name__ == 'inspection':
    function.__signature__ = ...

# <code>
```

**Edit:** More specifically, given a function `f(a, b)`, I wish to have it wrapped with a wrapper function

```
def g(*args, **kwargs):
    print(args)
    f(*args, **kwargs)
```

such that `g` will have the same signature in PyCharm. `functools.wraps` doesn't work.

Comment: The point of static inspection is that *no code is run*. Can you provide an example of how you want to patch the signature? This is usually perfectly doable without executing code.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi Thanks for your comments (especially on the irrelevant answer which is now deleted). The purpose is mainly copying (perhaps with minor alterations) the signature of another function. `functools.wraps` doesn't do the trick (perhaps a problem with pyCharm), so I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: I undelete what I wrote and your answer so it could be referred by others.

Comment: Let me rephrase that: Please [edit] your question to add a [mcve] of what you are trying to achieve, so that the question can be unambiguously be answered. You most likely have something like ``def a(*args, **kwargs): ...`` and ``def b(a, b, c, d): ...`` and want ``a`` to type-check like ``b``, is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check this, but according to PEP484, there's a variable called [`typing.TYPE_CHECKING`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.TYPE_CHECKING).

Comment: The point of ``typing.TYPE_CHECKING`` is *not running code at runtime*. It is not about *running code during inspection*.